# how come "turn in" means go to sleep?

Tags: etymology

I looked up OED,it says that "turn in" could mean "go to sleep",I just want to know how does that come?

Comment: Does it actually mean 'go to sleep' or does it really mean 'retire for the night', that is to say, retire to one's room.

Comment: The origin appears to be nautical.  https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/58/messages/1383.html

Comment: @HotLicks Having followed your link I find the idea that "turn in" is the opposite of, and possibly a back-formation from, "turn out" as in "turn out the guard" to be quite persuasive.

Comment: *When you [**turn in**](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/60/messages/454.html) for the night, you **go**, or "**turn**", **in** to your bed. In the morning, you **get**, or "**turn**", **out** of it. (You can also "**turn out**" the guard in a military emergency - this is a similar usage.)*

Comment: You might compare German *kehren*, specifically *einkehren*. I can't write an answer on that alone, but maybe you find something if you do a search. The dates fromdictionaries, which would post date a possible relation by far, are, as per ussual, entirely unreliable to rule out a perfectly fine analogy.

Answer (score 9):

Usage of “turn in” as an idiomatic expression meaning “go to bed” dates back to the 17th century and its origin appears to be from nautical jargon:

***[Turn in:](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/q6oyzny)***

1. to go to bed.

> 1695  [UK]    Congreve Love for Love III i: *I mean to toss a can, and remember my sweetheart afore I turn in.*

> 1751  [UK]    Smollett Peregrine Pickle (1964) 584: *You sister Mrs. Clover keeps close watch upon her kinsman, without ever turning in.*

> 1767  [US]    ‘Andrew Barton’ Disappointment II i: *Let’s step into the state-room and turn in.*

(Green’s Dictionary of Slang)

Unluckily GDoS doesn’t explain how turn in come to mean “go to bed”, but one suggestion comes from [The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/55/messages/482.html)

> I believe the space on old-times boats was quite limited and the sailors' beds (most probably of hamac-type in two tiers) had a very restrictive clearance to accommodate a person (which is the case even nowadays on small boats). Therefore the person to go to bed had to literally "turn in".

and also Etymonline suggests a possible nautical origin

[Turn in:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/turn)

> American English. Turn in "go to bed" is attested from 1690s, originally nautical.

and according to A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English ***[turn in:](https://books.google.it/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PA432&dq=%22fuck%20like%20a%20rattlesnake%22&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=turn%20in&f=false)***

> 1695 (Congreve) colloquial nautical till mid 19th century, then a general usage.

Comment: The historical list based on *when* helps us understand *how*. I add that one sleeping space was often occupied by sailors in sequence (what is now termed *hot-bunking*). So when one got up, the next took his *turn in* the bunk or hammock.

Comment: I think there might also be a connection to Webster: turn 4 c : a period or tour of duty : SHIFT (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn). So turn in might mean to leave the shift